# UIView created from XIB file is not showing

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, xib

I have created a xib file in my project which looks like this

[image]

I'm initializing it with this code

```
class MainItem: UIView {
    class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
        let view = UINib(nibName: "MainItem", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as! UIView
        return view
    }
}

stackView.addArrangedSubview(MainItem.instanceFromNib())
```

and I'm adding it to a `UIStackView` which already has some views like `UILabel` or `UIScrollView`. but the added view is not showing when I'm running the app and here is the result
[image]
[image]

what is the problem?

Comment: How do you add the MainItem, can you so the code?

Comment: you are using it wrongly, read this : https://medium.com/@brianclouser/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960

Comment: I've edited my code @ukim

Comment: In that way I'm still getting the same result @vivekDas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason is that you did not specify the height of the view, so the height of it becomes to 0 during the rendering process. There are two ways to do it:

1. Set the alignment of you stackView to .fillEqually. You can do this because the label has non 0 intrinsic heigh.

   stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
2. Tell iOS how to calculate the height of your view. For example override `intrinsicContentSize` of your view

Comment: I'm printing the height of the initialized view before adding and it's 128

Comment: The height can change after you adding it if there is no constraints. @Amir_P Can you also post the code you config the stack view

Comment: I've added the height constraint for the view inside. the config is done from storyboard(vertical axis with center alignment and fill distribution)

Comment: ok you were right there were no height constraint but I remember that I've added it. It's fixed now